# How to automatically create ranges in excel? Any formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[automatic ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kshu4.jpg)

eg:

```
RD
001-010
011-020
021-030
031-040
041-050
051-060
061-070
071-080
081-090
091-100
```

Comment: See my **NOTE1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start the range list in the first row, in **A1** enter:

```
=TEXT(10*(ROW()-1)+1,"000") & "-" & TEXT(ROW()*10,"000")
```

and copy downward

[image]

**NOTE:**

If you want to start the ranges further down in the worksheet, use:

```
=TEXT(10*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+1,"000") & "-" & TEXT(ROWS($1:1)*10,"000")
```

instead.